# How do you draw random numbers from a given scipy random distribution?

Tags: python, random, scipy, scipy.stats

I'm trying to generate random numbers from a given scipy stats random distribution, in my case a negative binomial distribution.

The documentation isn't entirely clear to me.
Unfortunately, the documentation is a bit sparse: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html

This should be really simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant method is `rvs` which stands for random variates.

You can generate a single random number drawn from a negative binomial distribution like this:

```py
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.nbinom.rvs(1,0.5) # returns 2 (or other random integer between 0 and +inf)
```

Comment: this should be included in the post not as an answer.

Comment: @Pygirl why? It **is** the answer. Or do you mean the link to docu? Sure, that could go either way.

Comment: `documentation isn't entirely clear to me` in your post.  `Unfortunately, the documentation is a bit sparse` in your answer. So I thought you have not found the answer yet.

Comment: Gotcha, rearranged a bit. Thanks for the comment.